# Pulsar 150 drifts right side

Tags: motorcycle, pulsar

3 years old, 25000km done. The main problem is that the bike pulls or drifts towards the right side. I took it to the original service centre where they said the front fork bent and they overhauled it and repaired the bend. Still the problem continued. So I went to a known mechanic who checked and he said there was a twist in the fork, which he also rectified. Now some what ok. But problem continues when taking turns or going faster than 40kph.
I dont know what to do. Even shock absorbers are also giving problem.
Is there any solution to this? Or can anyone can suggest good mechanic in chennai.

Comment: I'm not a bike expert, but would bet the front end needs replaced (entire front assembly from the frame forward, excluding the wheel and brakes and such). Once these parts become "tweaked" it's hard to get them to function correctly again. What happened originally to get them messed up, a crash or accident?

Comment: A twisted fork is better replaced. The entire front fork assembly with a new triple tree would put you back 7-9k INR though. Have you checked the front wheel wear? If it has worn unevenly, you would see such a problem regardless of the condition of the forks. I know of a decent mechanic in Chennai at Besant Nagar beach called Vallavan. At the far end of the beach. Do not have his number, will try to source it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing a bent fork will rectify a lot of problems. Using a bent fork will certainly cause a lot of issues. Low handling, lack of confidence while cornering and a wobbling effect while at high speeds are due to the different settings for the rear suspensions. When both rear suspensions have entirely different settings it causes all the above mentioned problems. Change both the rear suspensions or get is adjusted by a known mechanic. It wont cost you much.

Answer (score 1):

If the forks are fixed and no issues is with them then the issue can be with handles too. If unbalanced or a little bent, our muscles don't register it as an issue and use them normally thus creating the drift.

Also a unbalanced wheel can cause it too since unbalanced wheel worn out on one side more than the other side which can cause dents in rubber and cause one side of wheel to be a few millimeter shorter than other side thus requiring to drift for compensation to come into grip of the road.

Try driving on a straight road without moving or turning your hand and notice the change in straight line of driving thus bringing out the issue.